# Distinct tuple values from 2 columns for a dataset using R

Tags: r

I have a dataset that has multiple column records

```
    Origin    Destination      R    Total      y        z
    A.           B.            0      23       "dummy"  "rep"
    A            C             0      32       "dummy"  "rep"
    A            B             0      22       "dummy"  "rep"
    A            B             2      10       "dummy"  "rep"
```

I want to get the distinct origin-destination pairs where the rate is 0 and the total added up. For example, the result of this example would be :

```
    Origin    Destination      R    Total      y        z
    A.           B.            0      45       "dummy"  "rep"
    A            C             0      32       "dummy"  "rep"
```

I wanted to do the same in R. Can anyone advise me for the same.

Thanks

Comment: Here is how I would do it. (i) remove rows where R != 0, (ii) use tidyverse to group by Origin and Destination, then summarize the `Total` column. Come back with a more detailed question if this approach fails.

Comment: @January Thank you for your reply. I have done the tasks as you said. I removed the rows where R !=0. But grouping might clear the column Total as well. How do we handle that?

Comment: No, grouping will not clear anything. Can you show what you have tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

Yo can do the following:

```r
df%>%  
  filter(R == 0)%>%
  group_by(Origin, Destination)%>%
  summarize(R = sum(R),
            Total = sum(Total))
```

Are you expecting y and z to have always the same value? if so, you can just add `y = "dummy", z = "rep"` in the summarize call. Otherwise not sure of how you want to combine strings here.